# Google Analytics event tracking for forms (not hosted on site)

Tags: forms, google-analytics

My website uses the CognitoForms service to host contact forms. I am attempting to track form submissions in Google Analytics.

I am unable to add the GA Event tracking code to the submission link, since the form layout code is generated from a script on Cognitoforms' server.

Here's what the form code looks like on my end:

```
<div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/YILktGvUnUapdCST4DWGvw"></script>
<script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "12" });</script>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are no input elements or links I can modify to include the tracking code.

Is there a way I can include a script to the above code that would push the tracking code through to the submission link?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does their script insert an actual `<form>` element onto your page, or does it insert an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Their script inserts a <form> element.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is actually on your page, then you can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to know when the form is submitted. Event delegation has a significant advantage over inline event handlers because you can apply event delegation *before* the elements you care about are in the DOM.

Here's an example of event delegation that uses jQuery. It sends an event to Google Analytics anytime any form is submitted on the page.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
  // This code will run when **any** for is submitted on the page,
  // event forms that are added to the DOM after pageload.
  ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', this.id, {transport: 'beacon'});
});
```

*Note: in the above code, the [transport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport) field is set to `'beacon'` because form submits [typically unload the page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#knowing_when_the_hit_has_been_sent), and sending hits with the beacon method helps ensure they'll actually be sent.*

---

Alternatively, if these forms that you're interested in are submitted to external domains, you can actually use [Google Analytics autotrack](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack) and the `outboundFormTracker` plugin to capture this information (autotrack uses event delegation under the hood).